# Android - Smaller ActionBar Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, styles, android-actionbar

I want to have smaller `ActionBar Tabs`.
At the top there is the `ActionBar` and in next row the Tabs, have same height as `ActionBar`.
How can I change the height of tabs ?
I am sure with a `style`...

my current tries, no success:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- THEMES -->
<style name="actionBarTabTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/actionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/actionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabStyle">@style/actionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- STYLES -->
<style name="actionBarTabTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBarTabBarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">3dp</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBarTabStyle"> <!-- This style kills the design --> 
    <item name="android:height">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<style name="actionBarTabTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/actionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/actionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/actionBarTabStyle</item>
</style> 

<style name="actionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you set actionBarTabTheme as your application theme?

Comment: No, as the activity theme: <activity android:theme="@style/actionBarTabTheme" ...

Comment: With theme at <application > it's the same. The height don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give the parent of these style

```
<style name="actionBarTabBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">3dp</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Tab"> <!-- This style kills the design --> 
    <item name="android:height">3dp</item>
</style>
```